# How to use `Unique` & `Sort` in R

Tags: r, list, sorting, unique

I have a **LIST** (thought it was a df, but NO) in R.
All I want is to find the unique items "rowIndex" then sort them. (Eluding me today, rrrr)

```
run,parameter,pred,obs,rowIndex,Resample
1,none,1,0,2,Fold01.Rep1
2,none,1,0,8,Fold01.Rep1
3,none,1,0,547,Fold01.Rep1
4,none,0,1,1034,Fold01.Rep1
5,none,0,1,1041,Fold01.Rep1
6,none,0,1,1128,Fold01.Rep1
7,none,0,1,1135,Fold01.Rep1
8,none,0,1,1135,Fold01.Rep1
9,none,0,1,1135,Fold01.Rep1
10,none,0,1,1828,Fold01.Rep1
11,none,0,1,1828,Fold01.Rep2
```

My code is;

```
keep <- "rowIndex"
U_numbers <- unique(df[keep]) 
U_S_numbers <- sort(U_numbers)
```

I am getting held up by this error;

```
Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
```

Comment: Try `unique(df[[keep]])` or `unique(df[, keep])` to convert to a `vector` as `sort` works on `vector`s

Comment: @akrun Used: U_numbers <- unique(df[[keep]]) then sort() but now have; Error in sort[U_numbers] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: `sort[U_numbers]` - you used brackets where you should use parens. `sort(U_numbers)`

Comment: sorry all, just checked it, it is a LIST (?)

Comment: How did you check it was a list? Did you run `class(df)`? Because a data frame is just a fancy list.

Comment: @MrFlick I used 'typeof()`, I am not even sure how it got to be a list anyway.

Comment: `typeof` returns the storage type and data frames are stored as lists. You should use `class` instead to see how variables behave. It’s pretty rare that `typeof` will return useful information.

Comment: @MrFlick Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it.

```
sort(unique(unlist(list[, keep], use.names = FALSE)))
```